# Xcode 9 - How to customize a design in storyboards for just iPhone 5?

Tags: xcode

I'm using Objective-C and Xcode-9.

When using autolayout, my designs appear perfectly on everything but iPhone 5.

I am trying to see if I can edit my design for -just- iPhone 5/SE screen sizes without affecting my other design integrations.

I tried using "Vary for Traits" but it appears that all iPhone sizes are considered regular height, compact width while in portrait mode so editing the iPhone 5 on those parameters edits all phone sizes.

I think I'm missing something here but I'm not sure the exact keywords to Google.

How do I customize a design in storyboards to be unique for iPhone 5 only, but remain the same for other phone sizes?

Comment: How is the design unique for the iPhone 5? A lot can be done with constraints and the 5 isn't that much different.

Comment: I'm using UIScrollView to create a horizontal scroll view in an onboarding process to swipe between three views. With constraints it looks perfect on all screens, but on iPhone 5 it's not displaying the same as the others (there are some design flaws). I keep messing with constraints but can't get the same design to come out, so I'm hoping I can edit just the iPhone 5 design to fix it.

Comment: @EnricoMatassa Well, you can't, so stop hoping that. My answer explains how to modify the result of layout in code. However, it would be better if you tried to understand _why_ "it's not displaying the same" and why "there are some design flaws". But we can't help you with that because you have not described any of it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @matt. I examined the code for the UIScrollView and all of the views and compared it with an earlier revision of my code where I didn't have this problem (but had an older, unused design). There were 0 changes in the code and even with cleared constraints the old design worked, the new design didn't. When I integrated the new design in carefully over the earlier revision, I ceased having this problem. I can't identify the source but I think when I first put in my new designs they were placed in an embeded view that somehow screwed things up even after removing it.

Comment: Hmmm. When I've done scrollable multi views like you describe I've used a UIPageViewController to do the work. I'd suggest looking at that and avoiding trying to do a scroll view based solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any simple built-in way to design in the storyboard for just one device type/size. But you should not have to. You *should* be able to make your design work for any phone size through autolayout alone.

Still, if you really can't, just implement `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (or `layoutSubviews` in your view controller's main view) and adjust the layout "by hand". That is when autolayout does its work, so if you don't like the results, you can tweak them at this point "manually".